# SQL server check for null value

Tags: sql

I have a table and I am adding a constraint so if PaymentType is different than 'Check' to ensure that the CheckNumber is null. This is my table:

```
create table RegistrationHeader(
    RegistrationNo numeric 
    ,BillingID varchar(30) unique not null
    ,RegistrationDate date not null
    ,PaymentType varchar(5) check (PaymentType = 'CC' or PaymentType = 'PO' or PaymentType = 'Check') not null
    ,CCNumber varchar(16) check(LEN(CCNumber) = 16 OR LEN(CCNumber) = 15)
    ,PONumber varchar(30)
    ,CheckNumber varchar(10) default null
    ,primary key(RegistrationNo)
    ,constraint CC_CCNumber_constr check(
        (PaymentType = 'CC' and CCNumber is not null)
        or
        (PaymentType != 'CC' and CCNumber is null)
    )
    ,constraint PO_PONumber_constr check(
        (PaymentType = 'PO' and (PONumber is not null or PONumber != ''))
        or
        (PaymentType != 'PO' and PONumber is null)
    )
);
```

So, I have tried

```
,constraint CheckNumber_type_constr check((PaymentType = 'CC' or PaymentType = 'PO') and CheckNumber is null)
```

and

```
,constraint CheckNumber_type_constr check((PaymentType != 'Check') and CheckNumber is null)
```

and both fail miserably...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about:

```
constraint CheckNumber_type_constr
    check ((PaymentType = 'Check') or (CheckNumber is null))
```

If you want to ensure that `CheckNumber` not null for checks as well:

```
constraint CheckNumber_type_constr
    check ((PaymentType = 'Check' and CheckNumber is not null) or
           (PaymentType <> 'Check' and CheckNumber is null)
          )
```